# 6 INNER JOINs Gone Wrong?

Tags: sql-server, adventureworks

I have been told by my professor that I need to use 6 `INNER JOINs` to connect the info on these tables, but I am screwing up somewhere. I do not see anywhere else that has a departmentID to JOIN on to. what should I be doing then?

```
USE AdventureWorks2014

GO

CREATE FUNCTION ContactList()

RETURNS TABLE

AS

RETURN 
(
    SELECT  p.BusinessEntityID,LastName + ',' + FirstName AS Employee,
            ea.EmailAddress, jt.JobTitle, pp.PhoneNumber, 
            pp.PhoneNumberTypeID, pt.Name AS Type, hrd.Name AS Department
    FROM Person.Person as p
    INNER JOIN Person.EmailAddress ea
        ON ea.BusinessEntityID = p.BusinessEntityID
    INNER JOIN HumanResources.Employee jt
        ON jt.BusinessEntityID = p.BusinessEntityID
    INNER JOIN Person.PersonPhone pp
        ON pp.BusinessEntityID = p.BusinessEntityID
    INNER JOIN Person.PhoneNumberType pt
        ON pt.PhoneNumberTypeID = pp.PhoneNumberTypeID
    INNER JOIN HumanResources.Department hrd
        ON hrd.DepartmentID = P.BusinessEntityID
    INNER JOIN Person.PhoneNumberType
        ON pt.Name = hrd.Name
)

GO
```

Comment: What is the intended behavior of the function? Can you add syntax highlight to make your code more readable?

Comment: You only need the first 5 inner joins to get all the selected fields. If you want to see the tables where a column_name occurs you can interrogate information_schema,columns - select table_schema,table_name,column_name
 from information_schema.columns where COLUMN_NAME in ('departmentid','businessentityid'). If your professor is making you guess what he wants then he/she is a bad person.